# VBA - Populate Word document with CSV table values

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word

*I apologize in advance for my question, I didn't had much to do with MsWord macros till now.*

Until now I executed the script below to add one-by-one some well-formatted tables to a word document via a VBA Word macro:

```
Sub InsertTableToWord()    

Dim TCID As String, TCTitle As String, TCObjective As String

TCID = InputBox("Provide TCID: ")
TCTitle = InputBox("Provide TCTitle: ")
TCObjective = InputBox("Provide TCObjective: ")

' some code to format the entered data
Selection.TypeText Text:=TCID
Selection.TypeText Text:=TCTitle
Selection.TypeText Text:=TCObjective

End Sub
```

I had to execute the above presented macro 10 to 40 times for different TC* values.

What I would like to do now:

- store the TC* values in a CSV (done, 1st column TCID, 2nd - TCTitle, 3rd - TCObjective)
- modify my code to load the values stored in the CSV file and repeat the action until all the data from the CSV file is used.

Could you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most effective method is to use Range.InsertFile to bring the CSV file into the document then use the Range.ConvertToTable method to transform it into a Word table. You'll find a discussion and detailed code example in this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396